# Is there a simple way to add a C++ object to an existing Objective-C Cocoa application

Tags: c++, objective-c, xcode, cocoa

I'm struggling to figure out how to add a C++ class to a Cocoa application I'm writing.

I understand that by default Cocoa applications are compiled as Objective-C, and that Objective-C is a superset of C not C++.

I've tried setting the file types on my Objective-C classes to `Objective-C++ Source` and renaming them as `.mm` files but I'm still getting errors for my C++ class declaration.

Is there a simple/straightforward way to include existing c++ sources in a cocoa project? Or is should I just re-write my C++ objects in objective-c?

**Update**:

Ok it turns out that I was sort of wrong.  When I tried to compile the project using Objective-C I was getting the errors:

> Unknown type name class did you mean Class

Then when I change the Cocoa sources to Objective-C I'm getting a completely different error.  So this issue is resolved.

Comment: I've updated the question.  Here is the follow up question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13070907/objective-c-equivalent-for-the-objective-c-function-vm-deallocate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a simple/straightforward way to include existing c++ sources
>   in a cocoa project? Or is should I just re-write my C++ objects in
>   objective-c?

That's exactly what Objective-C++ lets you do -- you can use C++ objects and Objective-C object together. Bear in mind that you still need to use Obj-C syntax to send messages to Obj-C objects, and C++ syntax to call methods of C++ objects. But if you do that, your C++ and Objective-C objects should play together very nicely. If you're still having trouble, there may be some specific issues that we can help you with; edit your question to include the specific errors and the code that's causing them.

Comment: Thanks! I realized that the errors I was getting after switching things to Objective-C++ weren't related to my C++ code. So I've marked this as the answer and asked a new question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13070907/objective-c-equivalent-for-the-objective-c-function-vm-deallocate