# Objective-C++ equivalent for the Objective-C function vm_deallocate

Tags: objective-c, objective-c++

I have some Objective-C code that I'd like to convert to Objective-C++.  To changed the extension of the source files from `.m` to `.mm`, and I set the filetype as `Objective-C++ Source`.  However, now my project fails to build.  Its giving an error on lines that I call `vm_deallocate`.

Here is the line:

```
vm_deallocate(mach_task_self(), (vm_address_t)prevInfo, prevInfo);
```

And the exact error is:

> Use of undeclared identifier vm_deallocate

Is `vm_deallocate` restricted to Objective-C? Is there an equivalent Objective-C++ function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, since it's c.
This is more a header problem.

Make sure you have include in the right file

```
#include <mach/mach_init.h>
#include <mach/vm_map.h>
```

And it should compile without complain.